# How to find all the missing markup in WooCommerce template files?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, phpstorm

For example

```
<span class="price"><?php echo $price_html; ?></span>
```

I need to change some markup that `$price_html` outputs.

```
<del aria-hidden="true">
    <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">
        <bdi>
            <span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">$</span>
        15.00
        </bdi>
    </span>
</del>
```

I think a filter would do what I need, but the problem is I can't find the code anywhere to add to the filter I'm using PhpStorm search to find it.

I need to find these as well.

```
<ins>
    <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">
        <bdi>
            <span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">$</span>
        15.00
        </bdi>
    </span>
</ins>
```

`<img class="attachment-woocommerce_thumbnail size-woocommerce_thumbnail" >`
And a few others I need that with some insight on how to do this myself.

I was expecting to find what I need in the template files.

Comment: AFAIK this extra markup is generated in the appropriate hooks in the PHP code and not template. Default content/formatting will be in the WooCommerce plugin itself. But since those are hooks then they  final implementation can be in your current theme. I suggest you do the global search in the whole project

Comment: I Found one in `wc-formatting-functions.php` but the file is not in the template directory? what to do?

Comment: It's a hook. So add your own handler for that hook (using `add_filter()` function) where you will use your own formatting instead of the default one. Normally such handlers in your custom theme are placed in a file called `functions.php` that is located in the theme root folder. Please refer to WordPress documentation for that.

Comment: I know about `add_filter` but when using it, for example. `apply_filters( 'wc_price', $return, $price, $args, $unformatted_price, $original_price );` the `$return` is where the html is. Do I need just the one variuble for it to work. `add_filter('wc_price', functionhere, 10)` and take all the code from $return and place it in `functionhere`

Comment: Google for `woocommerce price format wc_price` to see examples of what and how many params are needed for this particular function. Inside such custom filter function you will be able to either alter the already formatted price (HTML that is generated by the original WooCommerce code) or create your own HTML formatting from scratch using the actual price value.